# Rigorously show that this program outputs $2n-$ #number of ones in binary representation of $n$ stars

Tags: loops

Given following program:

```
while n > 0 do
    for i = 1 to n do
       print '*'
    n = n / 2
```

where $/$ is integer division as usual. We want to calculate exactly how many * are printed. By summing up $n+n/2+n/4+...+n/2^{\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor}$ we get $2n-1$ but only if $n$ is a perfect power of $2$. In this case we can do simple algebra by manipulating the sum and using sum of geometric sequence formula. The problem is the integer division if $n$ is not a power of two. If we denote $s$ to be number of $1$'s in the binary representation of $n$, the result should be $2n-s$, but how to show this rigorously? My idea was to somehow show that for each $1$ in the binary representation, when we divide, we somehow lose the precision so $1$ less * is printed (because dividing by 2 is basically right bit shift).

Comment: I don't think this will result in $2n-s$. Increasing $n$ should increase the number of `*` you see, not decrease it.

Comment: Yeah, $2n-s$ Is strictly increasing in $n$, isn't it?

Comment: My bad. I thought you fixed $n$ to be a power of $2$, and $s$ would be the remainder. After re-reading your question it became clear what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a non-negative integer $x$, let $|x|$ denote the number of ones in the binary representation of $x$.

You can prove the claim by induction on $n$.
The base case $n=0$ is trivially true. Consider then $n>0$.
During the first iteration, the algorithm prints $n$ stars.
The number $x$ of stars printed by the other iterations is exactly the number of stars printed when the input of the algorithm is $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$.
Hence, by induction hypothesis, $x=2\lfloor n/2\rfloor - |\lfloor n/2 \rfloor|$.

If $n$ is even the total number of printed stars is:
$$
n+x = n+2\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - |\lfloor n/2 \rfloor|
=n+2(n/2)-|n/2|
=2n-|n/2|=2n-|n|,
$$
where we used the fact $|n/2|=|n|$ since the least significant bit of the binary representation of $n$ is a $0$.

If $n$ is odd the total number of printed stars is:

$$
\begin{align*}
n+x &= n+2\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - |\lfloor n/2 \rfloor|
=n+2((n-1)/2)-|(n-1)/2| \\
&=2n-1-|(n-1)/2|
=2n-1-(|n|-1)
=2n-|n|,
\end{align*}
$$
where we used $|n|=1+|n-1|=1+|(n-1)/2|$ since the last bit of the binary representation of $n$ is a $1$.